# wsdl2java custom bind types to specific java class

Tags: java, wsdl2java

Using wsdl2java, is there a way to bind xsd types to a specific java class?
My wsdl contains the following:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Dimension">
    <xsd:attribute name="height" type="xsd:decimal" />
    <xsd:attribute name="length" type="xsd:decimal" />
    <xsd:attribute name="width" type="xsd:decimal" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

and I want to bind all of the xsd:decimal elements within the 'Dimension' element to Integer (I have my reasons).

I was able to do it on a global scope using a custom bindings file with the following bindings:

```
<jxb:globalBindings>
    <jxb:javaType name="java.lang.Integer" xmlType="xsd:decimal"/>
</jxb:globalBindings>
```

but I only want to do it for these specific elements. I cant change the wsdl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using property binding:

```
    <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='Dimension']/xsd:attribute[@name='height']">
        <jxb:property>
          <jxb:baseType>
            <jxb:javaType name="java.lang.Integer"/>
          </jxb:baseType>
        </jxb:property>
    </jxb:bindings>
```